# Implied synchronization with MPI_BCAST for both sender and receivers?

Tags: synchronization, mpi, broadcast

When calling MPI_BCAST, is there any implied synchronization? For example, if the sender process were to get to the MPI_BCAST before others could it do the BCAST and then continue without any acknowledgements? Some recent tests with code like:

```
program test
include 'mpif.h'

integer ierr, tid, tmp

call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, tid, ierr)

tmp = tid

if(tid.eq.0) then
  call MPI_BCAST(tmp,1,MPI_INTEGER,MPI_ROOT,MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
else

endif

write(*,*) tid,'done'
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

end
```

shows that with two threads they both reach completion, despite only the sender doing a call to MPI_BCAST.

Output:

```
1 done           0
0 done           0
```

Could this be a problem with the MPI installation I'm working with (MPICH), or is this standard behavior for MPI?

Answer (score 1):

`Bcast` is a collective communication call, and as such blocks. More precisely, it blocks until all processes in the specified communicator have made a matching call to `Bcast`, at which point communication occurs and execution continues.

Your code is too simplified for debugging purposes. Can you post a working minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: OK, I've put the full program that I'm working with. I would expect it to block indefinitely waiting for others to call MPI_BCAST if mpirun is launched with more than 1 processor, but on my machine it exits with both processes making the call to write, with the value 0 in tmp

Comment: It does not need to block -- the root doesn't need any responses from the other ranks to continue, so it may not wait for them.  In particular, in an eager message protocol, the root will send its message immediately and it will sit in a buffer on (some of) the other ranks until they call `MPI_Bcast`.

Comment: @Jeremiah: not true. The MPI standard requires that by the time `Bcast` returns, the contents of the root's buffer have been copied to all processes. @user631027: In your program, process 0 blocks on `Bcast`, but process 1 immediately reaches `Finalize`, reducing the size of MPI_COMM_WORLD to 1. As such, process 0 is now free to complete `Bcast` since he's the only one to broadcast to. If process 1 were to call a `Bcast` that doesn't match that of process 0, the program would hang.

Comment: @suszterpatt: I think what you are saying only says that when the non-root processes return from `MPI_Bcast`, they have the data from the root; the root can have `MPI_Bcast` return as soon as it is safe to overwrite the buffer being sent.

Comment: This answer is not completely correct. From the MPI Standard v3 section 5.1: "It is dangerous to rely on synchronization side-effects of the collective operations for program correctness. For example, even though a particular implementation may provide a broadcast routine with a side-effect of synchronization, the standard does not require this, and a program that relies on this will not be portable.". `Bcast` is *not required* to block on all processes until the operation has finished.

Comment: @suszterpatt - This answer is not correct, according to the MPI standard. Blocking refers to the fact that the call should return only after it is safe to modify the buffer. The return does not indicate that other processes in the group have completed or even started the operation (see Section 5.1, MPI Standard v3 ). Except MPI_Barrier, other collective completions do not imply synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

I can attest that `MPI_Bcast` does **NOT** block, at least for the root (sending) process. You should call `MPI_Barrier` immediately afterward if you want to be certain that your program blocks. I know this because I recently accidentally called `MPI_Bcast` for the root process **only** (instead of collectively) and the program execution continued as normal until much later when the NEXT unrelated call to `MPI_Bcast`, in which the old buffer was received into the new different buffers. This mismatch in buffer data type/length produced garbage data and it took me a while to find that bug.

Comment: Hi MasterHD, I believe the reasons for the behavior you observed and the behavior that caused me to post the question originally are the same. MPI_Bcast is a collective MPI operation, which means that the MPI standard says all ranks must participate. If they do, then MPI_Bcast is a blocking operation. If they do not, then the MPI program is not compliant with the standard and you will see undefined behavior. In both of our cases, that undefined behavior was that the program proceeded merrily along its way as if nothing was wrong.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that if `MPI_Bcast` was truly a **blocking** method then calling it on ONLY the root process would immediately hang that root process without allowing it to continue. Was that your question or something else?

Comment: Also, @MasterHD, if your `MPI_Bcast` call had sufficiently large buffers that it was trying to send, it probably would have blocked on the root process as well. It only completed because you were probably sending small amounts of data that were buffered internally.