# Broadcasting from processes if a condition is met in MPI

Tags: python, numpy, mpi, mpi4py

I am new to MPI and and I'm trying to broadcast from one of the processes if a condition is met. The problem is that I don't see broadcasted messages on other processes when I try to print it out. When a process passes the second `if` condition it broadcasts a `numpy` array. In my code, processes 0, 1, 3, 5, 7 pass the second if condition. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

rand_num=np.empty(5,dtype='float')
bands  = [(0, 65), (66, 132), (133, 198), (199, 264), (265, 330), (331, 396), (397, 462), (463, 529)]
volts = {'map1':[478], 'map2':[346], 'map3':[213], 'map4':[81], 'map5':[34]}

for items in volts.keys():
    if(len(volts[items])!=0):
        neur_id = volts[items][0]
        if neur_id in range(bands[comm.rank][0],bands[comm.rank][1]):
            rand_num = np.array([comm.rank for i in range(0,5)],dtype='float')
            comm.Bcast(rand_num, root=comm.rank)
        comm.Barrier() #hoping to stop other processes from proceeding.
    print 'data and rank',rand_num,comm.rank
```

I was expecting the output to look like:

```
data and rank [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] 0           data and rank [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 0          data and rank [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.] 0          data and rank [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.] 0          data and rank [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.] 0  
data and rank [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] 1           data and rank [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 1          data and rank [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.] 1          data and rank [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.] 1          data and rank [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.] 1   
data and rank [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] 2           data and rank [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 2          data and rank [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.] 2           data and rank [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.] 2         data and rank [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.] 2
data and rank [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] 3          data and rank [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 3           data and rank [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.] 3          data and rank [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.] 3          data and rank [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.] 3
data and rank [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] 4          data and rank [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 4            data and rank [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.] 4          data and rank [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.] 4          data and rank [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.] 4
data and rank [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] 5          data and rank [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 5           data and rank [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.] 5          data and rank [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.] 5           data and rank [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.] 5
data and rank [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] 6          data and rank [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 6            data and rank [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.] 6         data and rank [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.] 6           data and rank [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.] 6
data and rank [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] 7          data and rank [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.] 7             data and rank [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.] 7         data and rank [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.] 7            data and rank [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.] 7
```

However, the output looks completely different. I don't see anything logically wrong with my code. 
PS: It has brought to my attention that this question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030922/mpi-bcast-deadlock). None of my processes are deadlocking. My problem is about synchronizing. I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653084/implied-synchronization-with-mpi-bcast-for-both-sender-and-receivers?rq=1) that MPI will not synchronize Bcasts if all the processes don't call `Bcast`, which is why I used `Barrier` immediately after `Bcast`. This was marked as duplicate by the fact that `bcast` was not called on all processes(ranks). If in my application  MPI's `bcast` can't be used as required then which MPI command should I use for "broadcasting"?

Since, this question was marked as duplicate, I couldn't answer it myself. I am posting my solution, I used `Send` and `Recv` over a for loop to solve my issue:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI
from mpi4py.MPI import ANY_SOURCE
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

rand_num=np.empty(5,dtype='float')
bands  = [(0, 65), (66, 132), (133, 198), (199, 264), (265, 330), (331, 396), (397, 462), (463, 529)]
volts = {'map1':[478], 'map2':[346], 'map3':[213], 'map4':[81], 'map5':[34]}

for items in volts.keys():
    if(len(volts[items])!=0):
        neur_id = volts[items][0]
        if neur_id in range(bands[comm.rank][0],bands[comm.rank][1]):
            rand_num = np.array([comm.rank for i in range(0,5)],dtype='float')
            all_ranks = [i for i in range(0,size)]
            all_ranks.remove(rank)
            rest_ranks = all_ranks 
            for ranks in rest_ranks: 
                comm.Send(rand_num, dest= ranks)

        else:
            comm.Recv(rand_num, source = ANY_SOURCE)

    print 'data and rank',rand_num,comm.rank, items
```

Comment: Deadlocking isn't a problem in my case, program runs completely. Synchronization is the problem. Please see the edit. `comm.Barrier` is being called by all the processes, it's outside the second `if` condition which means it will be executed even if the process doesn't meet the condition.

Comment: The symptoms may be different, but you are using `Bcast` incorrectly as explained by the answer to the referenced question. You must call `Bcast` on all ranks with the same parameters in the same order.

Comment: Is there any way for my case to bcast other than using `bcast` from MPI?

Comment: Given the distinct direction towards a solution for your case (rather than the original "why doesn't this work") I vote to reopen. However, your proposed solution is very fragile. This relies on exactly one rank going to the send which contradicts your description. Depending on whether exactly one rank will match and the data that is transferred or not you could use allreduce or possibly allgather. I do have some issues following your sample code / imagining what the real code might look like.

Comment: `for` loop over maps is a serial process. At any point of time only 1 of the copies of maps on all processes will `bcast`. For e.g: A part of 'map1' is on all process but only 1 of the parts of map1 is alowd to `bcast`. I editd the descrption. In my real application, there are 30 groups(maps) of neurons and 8 processes, each process wil have some of neurons frm each map. At any point only 1 nurn in each maps is allowed to update weights and it will share the weights with other neurons in the same map. I am using `bcast` because nurns belonging to same map are also there are on other processes.